# Want to encrypt password passed in "sql_alchemy_conn" in airflow.cfg

Tags: password-encryption

I have "sql_alchemy_conn = mysql://airflow_user:Airflow123@x.x.x.x:3306/airflow_db_one" variable inside airflow.cfg which is used to connect backend database.

I want to encrypt/hash my password "Airflow123" from airflow.cfg file

I tried fernet, I placed "fernet_key", "encrypted_mysql_pass" and "sql_alchemy_conn = mysql://airflow_user:{encrypted_mysql_pass}@x.x.x.x:3306/airflow_db_one" in airflow.cfg file.

with above change i got error stating "Access denied"